# Using a self calling function within a while loop C++

Tags: c++, function, while-loop

I am new to C++ and I am exploring the behavior of self calling function calls used inside a while loop. Here is the code I wrote

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void self_calling_function(int);

void self_calling_function(int i){
    cout << "Inside function :" << i ;
    while(i < 5){
        i++;
        cout << " I: " << i << endl;
        self_calling_function(i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    self_calling_function(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically I am expecting that once the execution enters the while loop and subsequently calling the function which calls back to itself, I thought the program execution should be returned back to the original while iterations. I can predict what happens if this were Java, but I am unable to understand this result given below in C++

[image]

<s>Edit 1:
The behavior I am expecting is that the state/value of i should be bound to the scope of it's caller. Meaning, say for the very first iteration of the while the value of i changed from 0 to 1 and 1 is passed to  the function. The next sequence of i is basically 2. But since we are calling the function which again calls i via the new while call, the state/value of i of the original while sequence is changed.</s>

Edit 2:
Here is the expected output instead.

```
Hello world!
Inside function :0 I: 1
Inside function :1 I: 2
Inside function :2 I: 3
Inside function :3 I: 4
Inside function :4 I: 5 // after this the code shouldn't go into the while as i is not < 5)
Inside function :2 I: 3 //Here we are continuing with the original while sequence i = 2 (which got lost)
Inside function :3 I: 4
Inside function :4 I: 5 // after this the code shouldn't go into the while as i is not < 5)
Inside function :3 I: 4 // //Here we are continuing with the original while sequence i = 3
Inside function :4 I: 5 // after this the code shouldn't go into the while as i is not < 5)
Inside function :4 I: 5 // //Here we are continuing with the original while sequence i = 4 and after this the code shouldn't go into the while as i = 5 is not < 5)
```

Comment: How is this behavior different than what you'd get in Java? Recursive calls work the same in both languages

Comment: What is your expected output? You can add the expected output in your question.

Comment: Java program produce the same output, see [it online](https://onlinegdb.com/vbiYo9w7i)

Comment: My guess is that you want that after all the recursion calls are done, you want to be able to get which function invoked the first recursion call.

Comment: I can clearly see that the value of i is changing when the function call iterations happen where it is forgetting the original state of i in the while loop. In java the concept of objects make the variables affected by the process which is calling it. I want to retain the state of i, If that makes sense.

Comment: @Thinker-101 You can make `i` a `static` if you want to retain state of `i`.

Comment: Not too sure what you are asking, but you can pass `i` by reference. `void self_calling_function(int& i)`

Comment: @AnoopRana Wouldn't making i static declare it as a class member? I think making i static will make it vulnerable to state change. Like function call can change i as well as the while calls.

Comment: The question should be updated to include **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Thinker-101 No, `static` keyword has more than 1 meaning in C++. See in my answer below, i think that should give you your expected output.

Comment: The kind you do the output might be a bit irritating! `Inside function: 5 I:5` are *not* the same function call – just as is not the next line either; with i == 5 the loop is not entered at all, but then there's no newline printed either. Maybe a good idea to debug and keeping an eye on the function call stack to see what actually goes on...

Comment: "The behavior I am expecting is that the state/value of i should be bound to the scope of it's caller" This is meaningless. Please tell us what you think *the program you posted should print*, and how it should be different from what it actually prints. Not how you would like to see its internal machinery.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Wsoce1eTf)'s a version of your programme outputting every piece of information on its own line and indenting output according to call stack depth. If you now see `Inside function 5` you will discover that there's no corresponding `I: <whatever>` below at the *same* level – however one level up such output occurs. With *your* version that output one level up would have been printed right following the previous output *on the same line* without you noticing that these are different recursive calls (see my previous comment).

Comment: *'But since we are calling the function which again calls i via the new while call, the state/value of i of the original while sequence is changed.'* No, it is **not**! Every recursive call has it's own version of `i` (unless you would pass it as reference as has been proposed already). The impression it might change arises from unlucky output (see my previous comments).

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for clarifying I get the point with this comment.

Comment: "//Here we are continuing with the original while sequence i = 2" No, this is not what happens. "which got lost" No, it didn't get lost, it is hidden below several *call stack frames*, and you eventually get back to it. I recommend studying the behaviour of this program in a debugger. Stop at the "cout" line when `i` is 5, study the call stack, and the value of `i` in each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comments i think you wanted the recursive calls to end once `5` is reached. This can be done by make the parameter of the function to be a reference type as shown below:

```
//-----------------------------v----->i is an lvalue reference to non-const int 
void self_calling_function(int &i){
    cout << "Inside function :" << i ;
    while(i < 5){
        i++;
        cout << " I: " << i << endl;
        self_calling_function(i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    self_calling_function(i); //pass i by reference 
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
Hello world!
Inside function :0 I: 1
Inside function :1 I: 2
Inside function :2 I: 3
Inside function :3 I: 4
Inside function :4 I: 5
Inside function :5
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dz2JN2ykF86fIQna)

Comment: The problem I have is like this. The value of `i` is now not changing via the while iteration rather it is changing because of the function call(indirectly). How can we make the original while sequence finish without strolling off into places where ever the code takes and finishing the program there?

Comment: @Thinker-101 It's not clear what you mean. You should add the output you expect in your question so that people don't waste their time in answering the question and at the end you say you don't want this.

Comment: @Thinker-101 C++ is an iterative language i.e. any kind of behaviour is executed in the order you specify – if you call a function recursively within a loop then the recursive call will start it's own loop while the loop one level up the stack still waits for completion of the recursive call.

Comment: @Aconcagua I have tried updating the question. But I get what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @AnoopRana So basically the usage of `while` is lost with self calling functions. If we could just remove the while statement and still have `i++`, the program will result in the same output you gave.

Comment: @Thinker-101 No, if we remove the `while` loop from my program then the program will keep on going without stopping. This is because then there will be no check `i<5` which earlier stopped the recursion.

Comment: Got you. But if we have the function call inside an if(I < 5) then maybe it gives the same output.

Comment: @Thinker-101 Correct, as long as we have a check to end the recursion.